Installing tree installed grub - is it something to worry about?
I just installed tree via
sudo apt-get install tree

and my terminal suddenly decided to update grub. Last week, I installed tree, and a similar thing happened. However, when I restarted my PC later that night it booted into a window displaying
Grub _

and didn't change.
Eventually I reinstalled my OS (I'm on WattOS, and just installed it on a new PC last Tuseday, so it wasn't the end of the world - it just took 5 hours to set everything up again).
Grub installed with a number of errors which I vaguely recall seeing last time (Included at the bottom of my post to make it easier to read).
I've googled around for :

Why does tree update grub?
Why did grub upgrade/update?

But I haven't had any luck. I suspect that I'm probably missing something.
Can anyone explain:

Why this happened
Does this mean anythings wrong
If I should/can do anything to fix it.

I'd rather not reinstall everything (for obvious reasons!)
Thanks.
Errors encountered when installing tree:
sudo apt-get install tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gimp-data libamd2 libbabl-0.1-0 libcamd2 libccolamd2 libcholmod3 libgegl-0.4-0     libgegl-common libgexiv2-2 libgimp2.0 libhpmud0 libimagequant0
      libmetis5 libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5         libsane-hpaio libumfpack5 printer-driver-hpcups
  printer-driver-postscript-hp python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-notify2 python3-    olefile python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-ptyprocess
  python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.sip python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-    accel vlc-plugin-samba xsane xsane-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 174 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 49.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 118 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 tree amd64 1.8.0-1+b1 [49.6 kB]
Fetched 49.6 kB in 0s (110 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package tree.
(Reading database ... 123032 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tree_1.8.0-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tree (1.8.0-1+b1) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.06-3~deb11u6) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this     setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /usr/share/wattOS/splash.png
Found background image: /usr/share/wattOS/splash.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-19-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-19-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions. Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries. Found Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) on /dev/mmcblk0p2 done Setting up tree (1.8.0-1+b1) ... 
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...

Update
I rebooted by accident, and my PC hanged again. I then reinstalled WattOS as the only OS on my hardrive, and everything worked fine. I just saw @eyoung100 s answer, and I ran
sudo apt upgrade

which ran with no errors.
Then I ran
sudo apt autoremove

which half way through gave me the same screen as last time:
The grub-pc package is being upgraded. This menu allows you to select which devices you'd like grub-install to be automatically run for, if any.
Running grub-install automatically is recommended in most situations, to prevent the installed GRUB core image from getting out of sync with      
GRUB modules or grub.cfg.
If you're unsure which drive is designated as boot drive by your BIOS, it is often a good idea to install GRUB to all of them.
Note: it is possible to install GRUB to partition boot records as well, and some appropriate partitions are offered here. However, this forces GRUB to use the blocklist mechanism, which makes it less reliable, and therefore is not recommended.

I haven't selected OK, as last time that gave me errors.
When I then tried in another terminal
sudo apt upgrade

It responded with
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 39623 (apt) 

Which is hardly suprising.
I tried closing that shell with ctrl-c and ctrl-x, but neither helped. I could close the window, but I'm concerned to.
More information asked for

Result of

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

is
8GET38WW (1.15 )


Result of

sudo dmidecode -t 0 | grep UEFI

is nothing. (I guess that means that it's not supported).

Result of

cpuid | less

is
bash: cpuid: command not found

All I can say is it's a Lenovo Thinkpad L520, it's refurbished, and I haven't changed the CPU. (I don't know about the previous owner).

Result of

sudo parted --list

is
Model: ATA ADATA SU630 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  231GB  231GB   primary  ext4            boot
 2      231GB   240GB  9449MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)

I can't see anything about fstype or gpt.
As I said, I attempted to install it onto a wiped disk.
Thank you for your time!

The embedding error is a problem. You do not install grub to a partition's boot sector PBR/BS. Or if gpt partitioning, you need a bios_grub partition. And you are using the old BIOS boot mode grub-pc. Systems since 2012 are UEFI and normally gpt partitioned. Then you normally have an ESP - efi system partition on gpt partitioned drive and use grub-efi-amd64, not grub-pc.

For some reason, you apparently had the grub package in a "installed but not configured" state, and after installing tree, apt tried to fix that. I don't know WattOS, but apparently it's a derivative of Debian intended for old/low-spec systems.It seems to have calamares installer as opposed to the regular Debian installer, so I don't know what is "normal" for it regarding bootloader installation. But the installer leaving half-installed packages for apt to fix later doesn't seem right to me.

See Update Section in my Answer.  Congratulations on breathing new life into an old laptop.

I removed the "SOLVED" tagging you added to the title of the question.  It is obvious from the fact that you have accepted an answer that the issue has been resolved (thanks for doing that!).

Narrowing Down of Errors
I see lots of things that need attention before we worry about grub

26 packages (at least) need removed.
174 packages need upgraded.
Grub needs a bit of investigation and a possible fix as oldfred's comment suggests.

We need to knock out the small steps (1 and 2) to keep from possibly having to fix grub twice.  These types of answers are what I like doing for 2 reasons:

I can help new Linux users understand that rebooting in Linux is way different than rebooting in Windows.
As a new Linux user, I hope that the OP will pass his knowledge on, like I am doing here.

Small Things First
Just from looking at the output snippet, I know that the package manager is APT, short for the Advanced Packaging Tool.  In case you need it, try mam apt.

apt update && apt autoremove - Should remove the 26 in 1 above.
apt upgrade - Should Download and install 174 packages noted in 2(which may include grub).  This may take awhile depending on your internet connection.

Note: The upgrade may abort at the same error the OP pasted in his question.  I would expect that, but we want the 174 package set to upgrade as many as is possible. If the upgrade aborts, continue with the Elephant and repeat step 2 afterwards
And Now the Elephant in the Room
Oldfred, well he's old, but he is right:
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..

Before we can reliably determine what type of grub install we need a few things in no particular order:

Your BIOS/UEFI version: sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
Is UEFI on/supported: sudo dmidecode -t 0 | grep UEFI
Your CPU: cpuid | less
Your Partition List and Table Type: sudo parted --list

For grub-efi-amd64 to work, you must have an ESP/EFI partition type of FAT32 and a 64 bit CPU.  Bullet 3 can be googled etc. as follows: Is family X Model Y CPU 64-bit, where X and Y are the integer numbers in the Family and Model Rows. Bullet 4 must contain an output of EFI Partition, fstype: fat32, and a Table Type of gpt. Bullet 2 must contain "is supported"
From the looks of the error quoted earlier, I'm assuming you attempted to embed the grub boot code into the root partition, which the installer formatted as ext2.  If the OP used the entire disk for the install, grub needs to be reinstalled using the entire disk.  This option will work whether EFI or not.  If an EFI partition exists, grub needs to be reinstalled in it only.  Please add the output of the above 4 bullets to your question, and I will update this answer with the appropriate command.

Update
Based on the updates the OP provided from dmidecode and parted I'm going to safely say that grub-pc is the proper grub architecture.  Since the OP has chosen to only install WattOS on the machine, we can safely embed grub in the boot-sector for the entire HDD with:
sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
After restarting, continue with: apt update && apt-upgrade  If grub ever needs upgrading again, just issue the commands above with each upgrade(In about 15 years of various Linux distributions, I think I have upgraded grub less than 10 times. It isn't a very common package to upgrade in my opinion).
Notes: By leaving off a partition number in the grub-install command, we've told grub it's acceptable to embed for the entire disk.
If update-grub fails (Issue these in sequence):

sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo reboot


Thank you so much for your answer! I've updated my question with the points you asked for.

It worked! Thank you so much! I couldn't upvote you as I don't have enough reputation, but consider yourself well and truly upvoted!
